# Listen for end of translation using ol.interaction.Translate

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm playing with the new Translate interaction (**[ol.interaction.Translate](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Translate.html)**) added in v3.9.0.
I am wondering if there is a way to listen for an event notifying the end of the translation?

Comment: Listening on "**change:geometry**" of the translated feature, the event is fired continuously while dragging..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a new event now : `translateend`

```
const myTanslate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
  layers: [myLayer],
})

myTanslate.on('translateend', evt => {
  evt.features.forEach(feat => {
    // process every feature
  })
})
```

PS edit: don't forget to add interaction to your map with `map.addInteraction(myTanslate)`

Answer (score 2):

Not as yet see: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4161 for a possible solution

Comment: event "translateend" is now available